# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J

Tags: java, opencv, mat, eventqueue

I'm doing OpenCv program in Java. This error keep popping up.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:24)
at application.Tester.<init>(Tester.java:245)
at application.Tester$1.run(Tester.java:274)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: `public void processEvents() {
  for(Runnable event: eventQueue.poll()) {
   event.run();
  }
 }`

Comment: I'm doing HoughCircle. Actually the code is quite long The error come at line eventQueue.poll()

Comment: Updated: my error is now
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(III)J`

Comment: There is something wrong with second line here, and i have no idea what's wrong with that

`byte [] data = ((DataBufferByte)rescaleimg.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
Mat mat = new Mat(rescaleimg.getHeight(), rescaleimg.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
mat.put(0, 0, data);`